# Popover does not display on hover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap popover, the popover does not appear on hover. It appears only when I click the link. I appreciate any help. TIA

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('body').popover({
            html: true,
            content: function () {
                return $(this).next().html();
            },
            selector: '.has-popover'
        })
    });
</script>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="div1" style="margin: 80px 0 0 20px;" runat="server">
        <a id="A1" style="text-decoration-style: dashed; text-decoration: dashed;" class="has-popover" href="#" rel="popover" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Title Goes Here!" data-trigger="hover">Hover for popover</a>
        <div id="Div3" style="display: none">
            <div style="float: left; width: 15%;">
                <img style="max-height: 75px; max-width: 75px;" src="style/x.png" />
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; width: 85%;">
                <ul>
                    <li>blah blah blah</li>
                    <li>yada yada yada</li>
                    <li>blah blah blah</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

By default popover is triggered by `click`, not `hover`.

You can change it by adding option:

`trigger: 'hover'`

So your script should look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('body').popover({
            html: true,
            content: function () {
                return $(this).next().html();
            },
            selector: '.has-popover',
            trigger: 'hover' // Add this option
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Interesting. That seems to fix the hover problem, however, now the html does not show in the popover; I only get the title.

Comment: @brad use `data-content="example text"` attribute on your popover element. I tested it here and it is showing properly: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2uUz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Pass `trigger` as an option to popover:

```
$('body').popover({
            html: true,
            content: function () {
                return $(this).next().html();
            },
            selector: '.has-popover',
            trigger: 'hover'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working jsfiddle check it out

http://jsfiddle.net/2DAZ2/43/

also check it an issue with popover with "selector"

So you need to pass additional parameter at the time of Initiation

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4990

```
$('body').popover({
            html: true,
            content: function () {
                return $(this).next().html();
            },
            selector: '.has-popover',
            trigger: 'hover'
})
```